# Unresolved reference: layout

Tags: android-layout, layout, import, android-databinding

I got an error in my code while binding

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main) in .layout
```

I want to resolve this layout reference issue

Answer (score 0):

DataBindingUtil needs type to be specified.
Try using following syntax

```
val binding=DataBindingUtil.setContentView<*YourBindingClass*>(this,R.layout.activity_main)
```